# MFC: How do you Paint a CTabView Background When no tabs exist?

Tags: winapi, mfc, ctabctrl

I what to display some text, probably using `DrawText()` on to the `CTabView` client area when no tabs exist to explain why they don't exist.  However, `CTabView::OnPaint()` is not called except once at the app startup.  Also when all tabs hidden the `CTabView::OnDraw()` is not called.   I suppose the `CMFCTabCtrl` may be the one getting the `OnPaint()` callbacks?  But nonetheless, how do you output something to that row/col of a `CSplitterWnd` occupied by a `CTabView` when all tabs are not shown (hidden via `CMFCTabCtrl::ShowTab()`). ??

TIA!!

Comment: Since CTabView is derived from CView, there must be called beside OnDraw other methods, such as OnEraseBkg ... did you checked this ?

Comment: The rot cause in your case is that CTabView is hidden ... you can check this ...

Answer (score 0):

The tab control works that way that all tab views are hidden - except the one which is open.

Where no tab view is open, none will receive a paint message (nor WM_ERASEBACKGROUND).

You could try implementing your paint stuff in the tab control's OnPaint handler.